# regex in python to match on strings separated with newlines

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a text:

```
type: some_type
text text text text
more text more text more text
abcd abcd qwerty
mode some_mode
```

So, I can match on first line: `"^[ \\t]+type: some_type"`. Now, I need to write `regex` to match on `type` and `mode`, which can be separated by arbitrary number of lines of text.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Also, that pattern won't work on the text you provided, because there are no spaces or tabs before "type".

Comment: What do you want to do after matching. A bit of python code can simplify a complex regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^type:\ some_type  # search type: at the beginning of the line
.*?                # anything else afterwards, lazily
^mode\ some_mode   # search mode at the beginning of the line
```

with the `MULTILINE`, `VEROSE` and `DOTALL` mode, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/EVAhDJ/1/).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^type:\ some_type
    .*?
    ^mode\ some_mode''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

string = """
type: some_type
text text text text
more text more text more text
abcd abcd qwerty
mode some_mode

type: some_other_type
text text text text
more text more text more text
abcd abcd qwerty
mode some_mode

type: some_type
text text text text
more text more text more text
abcd abcd qwerty
mode some_other_mode
"""

print(rx.findall(string))
```

This can obviously be put in a function with the type and or mode as parameter to be searched for.

Comment: thanks for you input, this didn't work for me though. May be ".*?" part of regexp should specify that preceding item is matched X or more times, something similar to grep {..} construct ?

Comment: @Mark: Have you applied the necessary modifiers? Can you share some of your original input strings?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, the problem was with missing MULTILINE modifier.

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense to loop through line by line the have conditionals for mode and type.  Refer to the pseudo code below

```
for line in lines:
   if type regex:
      do something
   elif mode regex
      do something else
```